# Segfault while importing torchvision.transforms

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I'm getting a segfault in python during imports.
This code:

```py
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
print("was there")
from torchvision import transforms
print("didn't get there")
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision import models
```

returns this:

```sh
$ python3 -u classifier.py 
was there
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

So `torchvision.transforms` seems to be responsible. I've tried switching the lines, and `torchvision.models` fails too.

I've also tried importing `torchvision.transforms` on it's own and there were no problems. What could possibly cause this?

Edit:

I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04.4 and installed `torchvision` through pip.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO; could you add a few details on how you downloaded `torchvision` and your platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I moved the `torchvision.transforms` import to above the `matplotlib.pyplot` one, and somehow neither `torchvision.transforms` nor `torchvision.models` cause a segfault anymore. It still caused a segfault with `torchvision.transforms` right after `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Here is what the final code looks like:

```py
import os
from torchvision import transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision import models
```

At least my code works, but I feel like there must be an underlying problem that this doesn't adress...